# Show that $g(x) := |f(x)|$ is differentiable at $c$ if and only if $f'(c) = 0$.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Suppose that $f\colon \mathbb R\to \mathbb R$ is differentiable at $c$ and that $f(c) := 0 $.
Show that $g(x) := |f(x)|$ is differentiable at $c$ if and only if $f'(c) = 0$.

My attempt:

We know that $f$ is differentiable at $c$ but we do not know what the value of this derivative is so
$$\left|\frac{f(x)}{x-c} - L\right| < \epsilon$$ (1)

for some $L\in\mathbb R$
and
$$\left|\frac{|f(x)|}{x-c} - G\right| < \epsilon$$ (2)

for some $G\in\mathbb R$

I want to claim that $g'(c) = 0$ and somehow the rest will follow. I am not sure how to proceed just using continuity and derivation.

Any help is appreciated it. Thank you.

Comment: In both of (1) and (2) the expression $f(x)$ in the numerator is wrong.

Comment: @LeeMosher Why? I think it's ok... but maybe I don't get the question. (English is not my native tongue)

Comment: @LeeMosher f(c) = 0; i was just restating the definition of differentiability

Comment: The definition of the derivative of $f'(c) = \lim_{x \to c} \frac{f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}$, not $\lim_{x \to c} \frac{f(x)}{x-c}$.

Comment: but f(c) = 0? so why even bother writting it? you are making a big deal about a small edit.

Comment: I see. You should put $f(c)=0$ into the body of the question, not leave it just in the title. I missed it there.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is easy to show that if $f'(c) =0$ then $g'(c) =0$. Just use the inequality $$\left|\frac{g(x) - g(c)} {x-c} \right|=\frac{||f(x)|-|f(c) ||} {|x-c|} \leq \left|\frac{f(x) - f(c)} {x-c} \right|$$ For the above we don't need the condition $f(c) =0$. But for converse $f(c) =0$ is essential. Then note that that since $g$ is non-negative and $g(c) =0$, it follows that $c$ is a point of minima and since $g'(c) $ exists it must be $0$. It is now almost obvious that $f'(c) =0$ by the inequality $$-\frac{|g(x)|} {|x-c|}\leq \frac{f(x)} {x-c} \leq\frac{|g(x) |} {|x-c|} $$

Comment: and you just use squeeze theorem to finish the proof? I really like the second part of your proof if so.

Comment: @mca2211: yes Squeeze is the key here.

Comment: How can it be explained the the $\frac{|f(x)|}{|x-c|}$ must be less than $ \frac{|g(x)|}{|x-c|}$.

Comment: Edit: I think it is simply true since $f(x) \le g(x)$ and $|f(x)| \le |g(x)|$ would follow the same statement

Comment: @mca2211 : note that for any real $y$ we have $-|y|\leq y\leq |y|$ and putting $y=f(x) /(x-c) $ and noting that $|f(x) |=g(x) =|g(x) |$ we get the desired inequality. Also note that just having $a\leq b$ does not imply $|a|\leq |b|$ (check with $a=-5, b=2$).

Comment: Sir, can you explain this point of your answer "since $g'(c)$ exists it must be zero $0$ ?

Comment: @AkashPatalwanshi: well, if $c$ is a point of local minimum or maximum and derivative at $c$ exist then the derivative at $c$ must be $0$. This is the first criterion for checking points of maxima/minima of a function

Answer (score 2):

(1).Suppose $g'(c)$ exists.

For $x<c$ we have $\frac {g(x)-g(c)}{x-c}=\frac {|f(x)|}{x-c}\leq 0.$ Letting $x\to c$ thru values  that are less than $c,$ we have therefore $g'(c)\leq 0.$

For $x>c$ we have $\frac {g(x)-g(c)}{x-c}=\frac {|f(x)|}{x-c}\geq 0.$ Letting $x\to c$ thru values that are greater than $c$ we have therefore $g'(c)\geq 0.$

Since $g'(c)\leq 0\leq g'(c)$ we have $g'(c)=0.$

Therefore $|f'(c)|=$ $\lim_{x\to c}\left| \frac {f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}\right|=$ $\lim_{x\to c} \left| \frac {g(x)-g(c)}{x-c}\right|=$ $|g'(c)|=0.$

(2). Suppose $f'(c)=0.$  We have $0=|f'(c)|=\lim_{x\to c}\left| \frac {f(x)-f(c)}{x-c}\right|=$ $\lim_{x\to c}\left|\frac {g(x)-g(c)}{x-c}\right|,$ which implies that $0=\lim _{x\to 0} \frac {g(x)-g(c)}{x-c}$, so $g'(c)$ exists and is equal to $0.$

Comment: How are the two limits in ($2$) equal? Isn't this assuming $g$ is differentiable from the get go?

Answer (score 0):

Say that $f'(c) > 0$ (for example). Choose some $0 < \epsilon < f'(c)$ and choose $\delta$ so that for all $x$ with $0 < |x-c| < \delta$ we have $\frac{f(x) - f(c)}{x-c} > \epsilon$.  What can you say about $\frac{g(x) - g(c)}{x-c}$ when $x < c$ and $x>c$?

Comment: $x<$c and $x>c$ imply x =  c but how does that help me? the denominator would be zero and it would end up $\frac{0}{0}$ and where does the implication of $x<c$ and $x>c$ come from?

Comment: I didn't mean that $x < c$ and $x > c$ simultaneously - this is impossible.  What I meant here was: Think about what happens in the separate cases of $x < c$ and $x>c$.  The behavior is different, and you can use this to prove that $g$ is not differentiable.

Comment: I see now. So the statements before "What can you say" are only there to make sure $f'(c)$ is positive without a doubt. And could we go as far as saying that $f'(c)$ is positive WLOG?

Comment: You'll need the $\epsilon$ in order to show that $g(x)$ cannot be differentiable (at least with the way I thought about this.)  Yes, we're assuming $f'(x) > 0$ WLOG, but you should finish the proof and check that you can also make it work if $f'(x) < 0$.

Comment: but the second part of the proof where you get the contradiction would not change much would it? I am just want to make sure I am understanding this. I mean i get a positive and a negative limit, so the next step is to say that this is impossible or do i compare it with $\epsilon$ and do something else?

Comment: You're trying to show $g(x)$ is not differentiable - proving that $\frac{g(x) - g(c)}{x-c}$ is negative for $x < c$ and positive for $x > c$ would not be enough.  You could still have $g'(c) = 0$.  You need to show that's can't happen.  Hence you need an extra $\epsilon$ of room away from $0$.

Answer (score 0):

My attempted solution using sequential criterion and help form the comments

$WLOG$ assume $f'(c)>0$ so $\exists (x_n) > c\ \forall n \in \mathbb N$ and $(x_n\to c)$ then $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(x_n)}{x_n-c} $$(1)

since $x_n > c$ then $f(x_n)$ must be positive.

So now since $g(x)$ is differentiable at c then
$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{g(x_n)}{x_n-c} = 
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{|f(x_n)|}{x_n-c} =
\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(x_n)}{x_n-c} = f'(c) $$(2)

so by sequential criterion, $g'(c) = f'(c)$

now choose a sequence of numbers such that $x_c < c$ and also $(x_n) \to c$ due to sequential criterion. thus$f(x_n) < 0$ so that the condition $f'(c) = 0$ remains true.

Now use this sequence into $g'(c)$

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{g(x_n)}{x_n-c} = 
\lim_{n \to \infty} -\frac{|f(x_n)|}{x_n-c} =
\lim_{n \to \infty} -\frac{f(x_n)}{x_n-c} =- f'(c) $$(3)

but since the numerator does not get to factor out $-1$ then the derivative is the same as $f'(c)$ but negative.

Thus, by Divergence Sequential criterion,$ \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{g(x_n)}{x_n-c}$ does not converge.
And $g(x)$ is not differentiable at $c$, which is a contradiction about our asumption of $f'(c) > 0$ $WLOG$ thus f'(c) = 0.

For the other direction of the proof, one must observe g(x) and use triangle inequality statements to arrive that it is differentiable at c.