# Prove that if $f$ is differentiable at 0, then the function $f(|x|)$ is differentiable at 0 if and only if $f'(0)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

I have the following exercise:

Prove that if $f$ is differentiable at 0, then the function $f(|x|)$ is differentiable at 0 if and only if $f'(0)=0$

[This](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2279967/show-that-gx-fx-is-differentiable-at-c-if-and-only-if-fc-0) problem is somewhat similar and the accepted solution seems correct to me. But I would like to know if there is a different way to solve it, also, the difference to the exercise here is that we do not know that $f(0) = 0$.
I hope you can help me, thank you.

Comment: It seems to me that the more important difference between this problem and the linked one is that you have the absolute value on the inside of $f$ and the other has it on the outside. Also, if you really need $f(0) = 0$ you can just replace $f$ with $g(x) = f(x) - f(0)$ and prove it for $g$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g(x) = f(|x|)$.

If $f'(0) = 0$ then ${f(|x|) - f(0) \over |x|} \to 0$ so  ${f(|x|) - f(0) \over x} \to 0$ and hence $g$ is differentiable at $x=0$ (and $g'(0) = 0$).

If $g$ is differentiable at $x=0$ then ${f(|x|) - f(0) \over x} \to g'(0)$ and ${f(|x|) - f(0) \over -x} \to g'(0)$ and so $g'(0) = 0$. Taking the limit with $x>0$ shows that
$f'(0) = g'(0) = 0$.

Comment: I just have a question, why is it possible to remove the absolute value from the denominator in the first part?
Thank you.

Comment: Since $|{f(|x|) -f(0) \over |x| }| = |{f(|x|) -f(0) \over x }|$, if the first expression $\to 0$ then the second must (and hence the quantity inside the $|\cdot|$ must also).